# Calculador binário em C

Tags: c, matemática, binary

Tenho essa função que converte decimal para binário, mas depois como faço a soma dos bits, ou usar o `&` (and), etc. ?

Usar o operador `&` temos de fazer a conta com 2 decimais? Ex:

```
25 & 25
```

Ou podemos fazer

```
11001 & 11001
```

A minha dúvida é como o compilador sabe que estou a trabalhar em binário? Existe algum método que possa colocar o numero de maneira a o compilador saber que realmente é um numero binário?

```
int main()
{
long long n;
printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
scanf("%lld", &n);
convertDecimalToBinary(n);
return 0;
}


void convertDecimalToBinary(long long n)
{
    int binaryNum[1000];

    int i = 0, j;
    while (n > 0) {

        binaryNum[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }

    for ( j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        printf("%d",binaryNum[j]);
      /* como consigo armazenar um numero binário? */

}
```

Definir como por exemplo: `binary num=101;` e assim dizia que `num` era uma variável binária.

Provavelmente não estou a conseguir exprimir a duvida de forma clara, mas tentei fazer o melhor. Procurei por aqui a ver se havia algo em binário para tirar a minha duvida, mas não encontrei.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A minha dúvida é como o compilador sabe que estou a trabalhar em binário? Existe algum método que possa colocar o número de maneira a o compilador saber que realmente é um número binário?

O compilador não sabe, inclusive não há nada que indique isso no código.

O conceito mais importante que precisa ser aprendido aqui que essa ideia de decimal binário ou outra notação é algo que serve ao ser humano. Para o computador nenhuma dessas abstrações existem. No fundo tudo para ele é binário, todo o resto é uma forma para nós entendermos melhor.

Quando escrevemos em decimal no código estamos apenas usando uma representação que nos é intuitiva. No código o número é um texto, até que seja compilado. Quando você manda imprimir um número na tela ou outro local está mandando imprimir um texto que representa o que o número que ele tem na memória. A forma de organizar o número na memória já é binário.

Então o que você vê na tela não é o número, é só um texto, por isso nem o compilador, nem o computador, nada no processo sabe do que trata este texto, mas mostrado para um humano ele sabe.

Então a função não converte decimal em binário, apenas parece estar fazendo isto. Ele pega um número e ele existe por si só (na maioria das arquiteturas ele terá 64 bits para manter seu valor na memória) e ele não está em decimal como parece. Aí procede-se alguns cálculos para pegar os bits individuais (de uma forma bastante ineficiente), e o resto de cada ciclo do algoritmo resultará em um número 0 ou número 1, ou seja fez-se uma redução. Este número será armazenado provavelmente em 32 bits, ainda que só 1 bastaria.

No final ele manda imprimir cada um desses números armazenados individualmente no *array*. Não tem nada de binário nisso. Há uma ilusão que tem uma notação binária acontecendo, mas só uma várias caracteres (sim, são caracteres) `0` e `1` sempre impressos uns atrás dos outros.

> Tenho essa função que converte decimal para binário, mas depois como faço a soma dos bits, ou usar o & (and), etc.?

Se quer operar no número não tem que fazer nada, opere neles da forma que precisa, não precisa converter nada. Os operadores de bits operam em qualquer número porque todos eles são montados com bits.

> Usar o operador & temos de fazer a conta com 2 decimais? Ex:
>
> 25 & 25
>
> Ou podemos fazer
>
> 11001 & 11001

Você opera em números, se por acaso seu código conte está escrito com um texto usando na forma que conhecemos decimal é irrelevante. Mas se que fazer usando binário precisa usar a notação binário no texto do código. O que está fazendo aí é aplicar o operador de *and* no número onze mil e um com ele mesmo, o que obviamente dará ele mesmo e costuma ser desnecessário fazê-lo. Se quer a notação binária no literal escrito no código tem que ser:

```
0b11001
```

Que você conhece como 25.

Provavelmente no fim quer fazer:

```
int num = 0b101;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/BinaryNotation.c).

Se quer que alguém digite zeros e uns e ele entenda tem que fazer a operação inversa, tem que validar se é um desses dois caracteres digitados (que podem ser convertidos para números automaticamente em alguns casos) e ir somando as exponenciações para chegar no número pretendido, o que pode ser simplificado com o operador de *shift* (`<<`). Novamente estamos falando da diferença da representação para humanos e como é representado internamente para o computador.

E foi o que eu entendi e consegui responder.

Comment: Seria mais interessante representar como `char num= 0b101;` ? deste modo utilizava so 1 byte, ou seja 8 bits. Mas para ter uma boa margem de numeros é melhor usar o `int num=0b101;` para termos 4 bytes, ou seja, 16 bits?

Comment: No caso de um número pequeno assim até poderia, um `char` é um tipo numérico de 1 byte. O `int` provavelmente teria 32 bits, mas isso depende de onde está rodando.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não vou votar já numa resposta para tentar ter mais respostas, para conseguir ter mais informações de diferentes pontos de vista. Obrigado