# Programa conversão de decimal para binário em C

Tags: c, linux, recursão

O exercício qual estou resolvendo pede para escrever um programa em C(ponteiro, alocação dinâmica e recursivo) que imprima um dado número inteiro em base binária.
Meu resultado esta gerando um número muito grande, agora não sei se esta pegando lixo da memória ou se meu código esta errado mesmo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

long long int binario(int *n)
{
   long long int *numeroBinario = 0;
   int *resto;
   int i = 1;
   int passo = 1;
   numeroBinario = (long long int*) malloc(sizeof(long long int));
   resto = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
   while(*n != 0)
   {
     *resto = *n % 2;
      printf("Passo %d: %d/2, Resto = %d, Quociente = %d\n", passo++, *n,*resto, *n / 2);
     *n = *n / 2;
     *numeroBinario = (*numeroBinario) + (*resto) * i;
     i = i * 10;
   }
   return *numeroBinario;   
}

int main()
{
   int *n;
   int *temp;
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
   n = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
   temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
   puts("Digite um número: ");
   scanf("%d", n);
   *temp = *n;
   printf("O número %d na base binária é: %lld.\n", *temp, binario(n));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que já respondi isso em outras questões (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/324267/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216284/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216128/101 entre outras), embora não no algoritmo exatamente igual. Já digo que este código é absurdamente complicado e usa muita coisa desnecessariamente. Veja como pode ser mais simples nos *links* acima. Entenda que até conceito do que está tentando fazer está errado, e vai prejudicar seu entendimento mais ainda se insistir nessa forma de fazer isto. Número é número e não tem notação decimal ou binária, texto é outra coisa.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @Maniero, mas é dessa forma que eu entendi e que me explicaram na universidade e as listas de exercício são assim também, até porque se fosse para fazer um código não recursivo seria mais facil, não entendo porque o bater na tecla em fazer códigos recursivos sendo que o espaço de memória que uma função recursiva consome para "rascunho" pode ser grande, vou verificar os links e tentar entender melhor o conceito, porque ainda esta muito confuso para mim.

Comment: Se mandaram fazer isso, o curso é ruim, mas eu prefiro acreditar que isso é interpretação de texto errado. E se mandaram fazer algo complicado assim aí o curso é muito ruim, mas acredito que não disseram pra fazer desta forma, nem faria sentido. Ninguém está falando em recursividade aqui, estou falando de não usar ponteiros, não fazer alocação dinâmica, e principalmente de usar texto onde deve ser texto e não inventar moda tentando colocar o que deveria ser texto em um número, isso faz zero sentido. Ñ existe número binário,existe representação textual binária,como existe a decimal que é padrão

Comment: O curso não é ruim, isso foi falta de interpretação minha mesmo e outra eu apenas mencionei recursão porque é o que o exercício pede a questão de utilização de ponteiro e alocação dinâmica foi iniciativa minha mesmo, já encontrei a solução nos links agradeço.

Comment: Não vejo porque usar ponteiro, mas pode ser só falta de contexto, alocação dinâmica aí é canhão pra matar passarinho. Deve usar só quando precisa mesmo, qdo ñ tem jeito de fazer no *stack*. Mesmo pra aprender, evite, e só use pra aprender onde deve, aí aprende certo..