# Problema com overflow em c, minha variável estoura

Tags: c

Esse código serve pra somar dois números binários e escrever o resultado mas no output aparece isso:

```
warning: overflow in conversion from 'long long int' to 'long int' changes value from '10100101010' to '1510166418' [-Woverflow]
```

Ja tentei mudar o long pra long int mas nao sei como posso resolver isso. pfv alguém me ajuda.

esse eh o código

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
 
     long binario1=10100101010, binario2=10100101010;
    int i = 0, sobra = 0, soma[10];
 
    printf("primeiro numero binario: %ld\n", binario1);
    
    printf("segundo numero binario: %ld\n",binario2);
    
    while (binario1 != 0 || binario2 != 0)
    {
        soma[i++] =(binario1 % 10 + binario2 % 10 + sobra) % 2;
        sobra =(binario1 % 10 + binario2 % 10 + sobra) / 2;
        binario1 = binario1 / 10;
        binario2 = binario2 / 10;
    }
    if (sobra != 0)
        soma[i++] = sobra;
    --i;
    printf("Soma dos dois numero binarios: ");
    while (i >= 0)
        printf("%d", soma[i--]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esquece isso, não é assim que lida com esse problema. Faça o código novamente agora usando *string*, porque não se converte números, número é número. O que dá para fazer é criar um texto com notação binária e apresentá-lo se quiser. O que a biblioteca do C já faz por você de forma automática é transformar um número em um texto decimal, e se configurar certo pode fazer em hexadecimal mas sempre é um texto. Em binário você precisa transformar em texto.Pode ver mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324260/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216128/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152947/101

Comment: Você não tem binários ali, tem decimais. Isto: 10.100.101.010 é por extensão dez bilhões, cem milhões, cento e um mil e dez, não é o que está achando que é.